# adjust font size when print

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i adjust the font size of the text when i'm gonna print it ? i tried to put font size property but it's no used when i'm gonna click the print button , it will just go back to the default font size.

```
            function print1(strid)
    {

    var values = document.getElementById(strid);
    var printing =window.open("");
    printing.document.write(values.innerHTML);
    printing.document.close();
    printing.focus();
    printing.print();
    printing.close();

    }


<div id="print2">
Ex : My data table 1
</div>

<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="return print1('print2')">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a CSS media query. In a style section add something like the following to increase the font size for the entire body. You can use any other CSS selector instead of body, so for just your div use #print2.

```
<style type="text/css">
  @media print {
    body {  
      font-size: large;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Add that to your HTML document after the `<head>` tag.
Of course you can set any other CSS properties in the block.

Here's a complete example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    body {
        font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }

    @media print {
        body {  
          font-size: 48pt;
        }
    }

</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

This is a sample document with normal size text that should print large.

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @bitfillder, its not working. how am i suppose to do that?

Comment: If you don't already have one, you need to add a <style> section to your HTML and put that in it. I'll edit the answer with some more context.

Comment: So sorry. I got the media query slightly wrong. I'll edit the anser and include a complete example.